# Search JSON name by Postcode API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm very new to jQuery, JSON and APIs, and I'm trying to build a small web app that brings up local hospitals in the area when users type in a a `service.type.name` and a `postcode`. For example, "Hernia Repair in N77JN".

I've got a small JSON file setup with some hospital objects that list their address and services.

```
{
  "places":[
    {
      "name": "The Whittington Hospital",
      "address": { 
        "street": "Magdala Ave",
        "town": "Islington",
        "city": "London",
        "postcode": "N195NF"
      },
      "service": [{
        "type": [
          { "name": "Hernia Repair" },
          { "name": "Hip Replacement" },
          { "name": "Crohn's Disease" },
          { "name": "Pregnancy" }
        ]
      }]
      }
      ...
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to work out if I can use this [UK Postcodes API](http://www.uk-postcodes.com/api) to reference the addresses in my JSON file and return results based on if the postcode matches or is within 3 miles of the search query. Apparently, you can do this with this bit of code:

```
http://uk-postcodes.com/postcode/nearest?postcode=n77jn&miles=3&format=json
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<form id="fetch">
    <input type="text" id="query">
    <input type="submit" id="search" value="Go">
</form>
```

And my JS like this:

```
$(function() {
var data;

$.getJSON('data.json', function(jsondata) { data = jsondata; });

function performSearch(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if (data == undefined) return; // do nothing if json is not yet loaded

    var search = $('#query').val();
    var output="<h2>Search results for " + search + "</h2>";

    for (var i in data.places) {
        for (var ind in data.places[i].service[0].type) {
            if (data.places[i].service[0].type[ind].name == search) {
                output+="<h3>" + data.places[i].name + "</h3>";
            } else {}
        };
    };
    document.getElementById("main").innerHTML=output;
};

$('#fetch').on('submit', performSearch);

});
```

With my basic understanding of JS, I should be able to take a search like "Hernia Repair in N77JN", which is stored in the `search` variable and `.split` it at "in" `search.split(" in ")`, which would separate that string into an array, giving me two values ("Hernia Repair", "N77JN"). Am I on the right track?

I like to think I can then use those two values to look at the Postcode API and bring up results for hospitals in that area. I'm just not sure how to go about this.

Any help with pointing me in the right direction is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var serviceName = search.split(" in ")[0];
var postcode = search.split(" in ")[1];
var matches = $.grep(data, function (e) { 
    return (e.places.address.postcode == element && e.places.service.type.name == serviceName ) });
```

Now use the `matches` array as you want. Hope it helps :)

Note: I think you should consider using two separate textbox for two inputs(postcode and service type), user may not always type **'in'** with spaces both side.

Comment: Thanks for this, but how can I match this with the Postcode API I linked to. Sort of unsure how to put it all together.